# T-SQL: What does "SELECT 1 BEGIN TRANSACTION" mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

I got this T-SQL code for error handling:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
    SELECT 1
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
END
```

I know that it inserts a 1 into the *#tmpErrors* table to flag that an error has occurred.
But I couldn't understand the following sentence:

```
SELECT 1 BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

I always thought BEGIN TRANSACTION was a executable statement by itself, but this seems now a pseudo FROM clause. Do you have any explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: That's why I still use semicolons :-) Just think of one after SELECT 1;

Comment: @Shnugo Not using semicolons has been deprecated since [SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563(v=sql.90).aspx),though still not absolutely required in [SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). As you probably know, semicolons have been standard since ANSI SQL-92.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL server, a `select` statement does not require a `from` clause.

`select 1` is a complete statement by itself, though in this case it is used in conjunction with a `insert into`.

`begin transaction` is a separate statement.

Basically the statement is saying "if there is no current transaction, log that, and create a transaction."

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 -- if no current transaction
BEGIN

    -- insert "1" into #tmpErrors
    INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
    SELECT 1

    -- Begin a transaction
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: And the `SELECT 1` really belongs to the `INSERT INTO ...` line above - it provides the *value* to be insered

Comment: Yes he's right. Basically the same as if you replace the `SELECT` with `VALUES`: `INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error) VALUES(1)`.

Comment: yeah, sorry if that was unclear.  `SELECT 1` by itself is a valid statement was my main point, it is completely separate from the `begin transaction`.  In this case the `select 1` is just used in conjunction with an `insert into`

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit out of context but i think this should check if any transaction is active. If no transaction is active: log an error and start a transaction.

this block inserts an error flag:

```
INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
SELECT 1
```

and this starts a new transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

so `SELECT  1`belongs to the insert statement and has nothing to do with the follow `begin transaction`command...